# How to create a link in Sinatra that points to a directory of files?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have an application that calls an other application that populates a directory.  Once it is finished I want to provide a link to the directory that contains the created files and people can examine or download them via the browser:

For example this works to provide a link to a single file: (Note this uses HAML) but the idea is the same

```
%p
  - output_href = File.join("..","..","test_runs",File.basename(@dealclick_test_run.result_filename) )
  Result file =
  %a{:id => "result-file", :href => "#{output_href}"}
    = File.basename(@dealclick_test_run.result_filename)`
```

The corresponding code for the directory doesn't work:

```
 %p
    Results:
    - output_href = File.join("..","..","test_runs",File.basename(@dp_test_run.result_filename) )
   %a( id = "dealprocessor_results" href = "#{output_href}" )
    = File.basename(@dp_test_run.result_filename)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%a( id = "dealprocessor_results" href = "#{output_href}" )
```

should be

```
%a(:id = "dealprocessor_results" :href = "#{output_href}" )
```